# Postgres Timestamp column with Java util.Date

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, jodatime

I have a (start_time) column which is of type timestamp with time zone. and I have a JPA mapping entity which reads as below,

```
@Column(name = "start_time")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date startTime;// (util.date)
```

My table has value "2017-08-09 09:57:00+05:30".  When I use JPA to map the values, I get the value as "2017-08-09 09:57:00.0"

when I try to debug, I can see CDATE inside the date attribute which shows me the correct value with timezone. How to map this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change `@Column(name = "start_time")` on `@Column(name = "start_time", columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE")`